# How do I account for presence of a dielectric medium while calculating potential due to a point charge?

Tags: electrostatics

I am not sure but I believe that the potential due to a point charge will reduce if the entire setup is kept in a dielectric medium. How do I account for it in deriving the potential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an extended medium the field is reduced by a factor of $\epsilon$ and hence the same for the potential.